# Why does Symfony form not validate my DTO with constraint annotations?

Tags: php, symfony

So I have a DTO, like so:

```php
namespace App\DTO;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Task
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    public $title;
}
```

And a FormType:

```php
namespace App\Form;

use App\DTO\Task;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TaskFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Task::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And a `TypeTestCase` like so:

```php
namespace App\Tests\Entity;

use App\DTO\Task;
use App\Form\TaskFormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;

class TaskTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    public function testValidation()
    {
        $task = new Task;

        $form = $this->factory->create(TaskFormType::class, $task);
        $form->submit([]); // empty data should trigger a validation error

        dump(
            $form->isValid(),
            $form->getErrors(true)->getChildren(),
            $task
        );
    }
}
```

The dump shows that the form is considered valid, there are no errors and it shows that `$task` has its `title` property set to `null`. Which shouldn't be considered valid, since I say that it's not allowed to be blank.

Of course I'm showing a simplified example here. In my actual code I'm validating way more properties, but all of them are ignored. It seems like `Form` is completely ignoring annotation based validation. Any idea why?

Comment: Im experiencing a similar problem in my project and try figuring out whats going wrong. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No sorry, I just went a different route in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! If youre still interested, I found a workaround:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63999633/symfony-validatorcomponent-annotationmapping-in-formcomponent

Answer (score 2):

You did not show us your `framework.yml` configuration so I am guessing here you are maybe missing some config:

```
framework:
    validation:
        enabled: true
        enable_annotations: true
```

Can you check that? Hope this is the issue otherwise you will have to provide us with some kind of stacktrace rather than say "the form is valid". Also do not forget to clear your cache after make any changes to your configuration.

Comment: I did not have that configuration, but adding it made no difference whatsoever. (And yes I cleared my cache after making those changes). How could I give you a relevant stack trace if no exception is thrown?

Comment: Not sure if you have the bundle installed but what about if you try `composer require symfony/validator`? Just in case :)

Comment: It's installed, I'm sure of that :-)